# Error python : [ZeroDivisionError: division by zero]

Tags: python

I faced an error when I run my program using python:
The error is like this:

```
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

My program is similar to this:

```
In [55]:

x = 0
y = 0
z = x/y
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-30b5d8268cca> in <module>()
      1 x = 0
      2 y = 0
----> 3 z = x/y

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Thus, I want to ask, how to avoid that error in python. My desired output is `z = 0`

Comment: What value do you want for `1/0`? For `0/0`, any value at all makes some sense (because `x/y==z` still implies `z**y==x`), but for anything else divided by 0, no value makes sense (unless you have an infinite integer, and define `infinity*0 == 0`).

Comment: There is an error in your logic if you come across a situation where you are dividing by zero.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Catch the error and handle it:

```
try:
    z = x / y
except ZeroDivisionError:
    z = 0
```

Or check before you do the division:

```
if y == 0:
    z = 0
else:
    z = x / y
```

The latter can be reduced to:

```
z = 0 if y == 0 else (x / y)
```

Or if you're sure `y` is a number, which implies it`s truthy if nonzero:

```
z = (x / y) if y else 0
z = y and (x / y)   # alternate version
```

Comment: I think the exception version is faster since the interpreter does not have to go through the if condition, at least if the exception occurs rarely.

Answer (score 4):

Returning zero instead of the division by zero error can be accomplished with a Boolean operation.

```
z = y and (x / y)
```

Boolean operations are evaluated left to right and return the operand, not `True` or `False`.

If `y` is `0`, the value returned is `y`. If `y` is different from `0`, the right side of the operation is executed and the value returned is `x / y`

Answer (score 1):

**ZeroDivisionError: division by zero**

```
a = 10
b = 0
c = a/b
```

This would cause the type error because you are dividing by zero.

---

**To solve this issue:**

```
a = 10
b = 0
c = ( a / b ) if b != 0 else 0
print c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# we are dividing until correct data is given
executed = False
while not executed:
    try:
        a = float(input('first number --> '))
        b = float(input('second number --> '))
        z = a / b
        print(z)
        executed = True
    except ArithmeticError as arithmeticError:
        print(arithmeticError)
    except ValueError as valueError:
        print(valueError)
    except Exception as exception:
        print(exception)
```